# Internal Server Error : Passing JavaScript object to C#

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery

I am getting a 500 (Internal Server Error) and I don't know why. 
I just want to pass a Javascript object to a C# function.

This is the Javascript function :

```
function validateImpact(id_dcr) {
    $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/ModifyDocument/ImpactAssesment',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
        id: 0,
        quality: $("#quality").is(":checked"),
        spares: $("#spares").is(":checked"),
        supply: $("#supply").is(":checked"),
        methods: $("#methods").is(":checked"),
        mp: $("#mp").is(":checked"),
        organization: $("#organization").is(":checked"),
        procurement: $("#procurement").is(":checked"),
        logistic: $("#logistic").is(":checked"),
        health: $("#health").is(":checked"),
        software: $("#software").is(":checked"),
        details: $("#details").val(),
        id_dcr: id_dcr
    },
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data);
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, error) {
        alert(xhr.status);
        alert('Error: ' + xhr.responseText);
    }
});
```

This is the C# method definition that'll be call in the JavaScript function:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ImpactAssesment(Impact impact){ 
    //Do something 
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "ModifyDocument");
}
```

This is the C# class name "Impact" :

```
public partial class impact
{
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public bool quality { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public bool spares { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public bool supply { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public bool methods { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public bool mp { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public bool organization { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public bool procurement { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public bool logistic { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public bool health { get; set; }

    [StringLength(1073741823)]
    public string details { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public bool software { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int id_dcr { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("id_dcr")]
    public virtual dcr dcr { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: `ImpactAssesment` does not return anything that code shouldn't even compile

Comment: @Dalorzo yes it does. It is returning :             return RedirectToAction("Index", "ModifyDocument");

Comment: First thing to do when debugging an AJAX request; check the network tab of the console to see the state of the request and the error message it's throwing

Comment: for sure i agree that you need to really use chrome dev tools to see exactly what structure is getting passed out. flying blindly on an error page will definitely yield minimal results and take a lot of time to resolve

Comment: Get Fiddler... it'll (very easily) give you details on the response that's otherwise difficult to obtain with ajax calls (so you can see the error page returned - usually just enough to kick in the right direction).  http://www.telerik.com/fiddler (can't live without it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are using an MVC controller (and not a web api), so you should remove the `dataType: 'json'` option

Comment: While this may help, it wouldn't cause a 500 error.

Comment: First rule of debugging: when you don't know what's wrong, you first fix what you know isn't right.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan well, OP should've inluded a stack trace at least, but I've had this kind of errors with WCF